# Find eigenvalues and eigenvector analitically

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider a matrix $M$ so that

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

We want to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of that matrix so, as the rule says, we have to solve

$$ \det(M - \lambda I) = 0 $$

Developing this equation gives us something of the form

$$ A\lambda^2 + B\lambda + C = 0 $$

We know that this equation admits either two real solutions, or one real solution or two imaginary solutions.

**Q1**: what does mean having two imaginary solutions in the case of eigenvalues?

**Q2**: what does imply having a single solution? Is this even possible ?

Let $ \lambda_i $ be the i-th solution to the above equation. In order to find the eigenvector $v_i = [v_{i1}, v_{i2}]^T$ associated to $\lambda_i$, we have to solve

$$ (M - \lambda_i I)v_i = 0 $$

For each eigenvalue, this gives a system of two equations with two unknowns:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(a - \lambda_i)v_{i1} + bv_{i2} = 0 (Eq1) \\
cv_{i1} + (d - \lambda_i)v_{i2} = 0 (Eq2) \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

In order to solve this, I know of two methods:

1. substract: $(Eq1)*c - (Eq2)*(a - \lambda_i)$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c(a - \lambda_i)v_{i1} + cbv_{i2} - (a - \lambda_i)cv_{i1} - (a - \lambda_i)(d - \lambda_i)v_{i2} = 0 \\
cbv_{i2} - (a - \lambda_i)(d - \lambda_i)v_{i2} = 0 \\
\left ( cb - (a - \lambda_i)(d - \lambda_i) \right ) v_{i2} = 0 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The only solution I see is $v_{i2} = 0$ which leads to $v_{i1} = 0$ and is not what I expect..

2. substitution

We can re-write $v_{i1} $ from equation (Eq1) with

$$ v_{i1} = -\frac{b}{(a - \lambda_i)}v_{i2} $$

Which gives in equation (Eq2)

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
-c\frac{b}{(a - \lambda_i)}v_{i2} + (d - \lambda_i)v_{i2} = 0 \\
\left( (d - \lambda_i) - \frac{b}{(a - \lambda_i)} \right ) v_{i2} = 0 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

The only solution I see is $v_{i2} = 0$ which leads to $v_{i1} = 0$ and is not what I expect either..

3. Lets consider the following practical example:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It accepts $\lambda_1 = 1$ and $\lambda_2 = 3$ as eigenvalues.

Now going back to equations to find out their associated eigenvectors, we are supposed to find $v_1 = [ 1, -1 ]^T $ for $\lambda_1 = 1$, and $v_2 = [ 1, 1 ]^T$ for $\lambda_2 = 3$ ..

**Q3**: What is the right approach to this problem? Have I done anything wrong or misunderstood something at some point?

**Q4**: The provided example may be a particular case (?), are there some rules which may help decide the way to go for solving theses equations ?

Comment: Q1: Take the diagonal matrix $M=diag(i,-i)$. It has two imaginary eigenvalues. Q2: What about $M=0$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde having $M=0$ implies M is a scalar when only one eigenvalue?

Comment: @Moo Interesting link. I found there was the determinant involved when doing my calculation but didn't notice the trace. According to the paper, this seems to be only valid for 2x2 matrix. I don't get which part of the paper helps resolving the eighenvectors though ..

Comment: Jib, a quadratic polynomial $x^2=0$ has one root, but with multiplicity $2$. So $M=0\in M_2(K)$ has the eigenvalues $0$ and $0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks for the clarification. I appreciate it and now better understand. Any idea regarding Q3, Q4?

Comment: Solve the equation $Mv=\lambda v$ for $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and given $a,b,c,d$ in $M$. Do an example, say $a=1, b=2, c=3,d=4$. Have a look into a book of linear algebra. Eingenvectors are always explained.

Comment: @DietrichBurde As I am far from being a mathematician I spent some times digging literature and experimenting before coming around ;-) There are plenty examples out there which let me get started on the right track. Now I would like to generalize the process (thus the reason why there is no value for $M$) and then I faced a few issues (which are probably not for you). As you can see in the question, I provided some details showing the steps I took until I got stuck..

Comment: @DietrichBurde The clue was in the way to pose the equation $Mv=\lambda v$ is equivalent to $(M -\lambda I)v = 0$ but let me get the relation between $v_{i1}$ and $v_{i2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dietrich and @Moo who commented with pieces of information which helped me get my way out!

**Q1**: Having eigenvalues being imaginary seems not to imply anything different
from having eigenvalues being real.

**Q2**: Having a single eigenvalue means that the diagonal matrix has multiple
time the same eigenvalue. And so it is for the eigenvectors.

**Q3**: The solution is to rewrite the equation in order to get a relation between the terms of the eigenvector, **NOT A PARTICULAR VALUE**.

In the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

And knowing that

$ (M -\lambda I)v = 0  <=>  Mv = \lambda v $

We get

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
av_{i1} + bv_{i2} = \lambda v_{i1} \\
cv_{i1} + dv_{i2} = \lambda v_{i2} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Which we solve by subtraction

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
acv_{i1} + cbv_{i2} = c\lambda v_{i1} \\
acv_{i1} + adv_{i2} = a\lambda v_{i2} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(cb - ad)v_{i2} = \lambda cv_{i1} - \lambda av_{i2} \\
v_{i2} = \frac{c\lambda}{a\lambda + cb - ad} v_{i1} \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

For the particular matrix provided as an example in the original question

$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

We obtain for $ \lambda_1 = 1$ the relation $ v_{12} = -v_{11}$ and for $ \lambda_2 = 3$ the relation $ v_{22} = v_{21}$.

Thus we can have a multitude of valid eigenvectors as long as the relation is satisfied. One set of them could be $v_1 = [ 1, -1 ]^T$ and $v_2 = [ 1, 1 ]^T$.